# Convert hex to decimal in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have hex numbers, and I want to convert them into decimal numbers. For example, 01 -> 1,  09 -> 9, 12 -> 18.

I tried:

```
01.unpack("n")
```

but that failed.

```
"01".unpack("n") # => [12337]
```

That is not what I want.

Do you know the correct answer?

Comment: Whether they are hex or decimal, numbers are numbers. There is no distinction. Do you mean you have strings representing numbers in hex?

Answer (score 33):

`String#to_i` accepts an extra argument, which is the number base to use. Hexadecimal is base 16, so the following will work for you:

```
"01".to_i(16)
```

Calling the `Integer` function on it will also work, so long as the number has an `0x` prefix:

```
Integer("0x01")
```

Comment: Important difference: `"g".to_i(16)` is 0, `Integer("g",16)` is an ArgumentError.

Comment: Thanks, perfect solution.

Comment: @user2909180 No problem. Please accept this answer by clicking the green checkmark beside it to make the question appear as solved.

Comment: @user2909180 You're supposed to _accept_ this answer.